# Find port traffic on remote host

Tags: windows, windows-xp, port

I have a machine that is inconvenient to access physically as it is on a another campus.
It is running XP with no software firewall, the firewall being handled by a hardware Sonic device that I don't control, and connects through a VPN. I can ping the machine just fine and that's about it. It does not have any shares.

I have the local administrator credentials but remote desktop is not enabled. It's running an app that is broadcasting traffic on a specific port and I need to find which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there another computer on that network which you have more access to - a remote desktop, a terminal?

If so, you can use nmap to see what's active on your machine, or you can run a packet sniffer to grab broadcasts from your machine.

[EDIT]

If the machine is physically separate BUT on the same network as you currently are, then a packet sniffer can be used from your local computer.

Comment: NMap has a nice looking GUI that was more thorough than AngryIP. Thanks!

Comment: glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [angryIP](http://www.angryip.org/w/About). It does network and optionally port scanning.